# Retrieve my comments on friend's Facebook posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

I remember I commented on a friend's post some years back, but I cannot find the post. Also, in our friendship page I have no access to posts where we both interacted.

Given a friend, how can I retrieve all his/her posts where I commented on?

Is it possible that some posts where I commented are now hidden to me?

Answer (score 1):

Possible your friend has deleted the post.

If not, you can search your friend's all posts. Go to his Timeline and scroll down little bit, you will see three tabs on left upper corner: **FriendName**, **Timeline**, **Recent**.
Click *Recent* and select year, the page will auto scroll back and a fourth tab will appear: **All Post**.
Click *All Post* and select month, after the auto scroll look for the post you are looking.

You can search for the same from your Timeline also.
Go to your profile, click on **View Activity Log**, on the left hand side click on **Comment**, select year from the right hand side. It will auto scroll and show all the comments by you month wise starting from December.

Comment: Doing like this I find myself searching in hundreds of posts... I was looking for the intersection between my comments and my friend's posts, but maybe it is not possible without some external tool.

Comment: As per my knowledge its not possible, I don't know any external tool to do this job. Interaction shows those post where you both are tagged, not comments or likes.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much anyway. The only thing I can think of is some kind of scraping tool, but I know none for facebook.